# percentage difference of datetime object

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a new column which contains the values of column diff(s) but in percentage.

```
    Finish Time                    diff (s)
0   1900-01-01 00:42:43.500    0 days 00:00:00
1   1900-01-01 00:44:01.200    0 days 00:01:17
2   1900-01-01 00:44:06.500    0 days 00:01:23
3   1900-01-01 00:44:29.500    0 days 00:01:46
4   1900-01-01 00:44:47.500    0 days 00:02:04
```

to further understand the data:

```
df["diff(s)"] = df["Finish Time"] - min(df["Finish Time"])

Finish Time     datetime64[ns]
diff (s)       timedelta64[ns]
dtype: object

df["diff(%)"] = ((df["Finish Time"]/min(df["Finish 
                 Time"]))*100)
```

-> results in this error

```
TypeError: cannot perform __truediv__ with this index type: 
DatetimeArray
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how are defined percentages - if need divide by summed timedeltas:

```
df["diff(s)"] = df["Finish Time"] - df["Finish Time"].min()
df["diff(%)"] = (df["diff(s)"] / df["diff(s)"].sum()) * 100
print (df)
              Finish Time                diff(s)    diff(%)
0 1900-01-01 00:42:43.500        0 days 00:00:00   0.000000
1 1900-01-01 00:44:01.200 0 days 00:01:17.700000  19.887382
2 1900-01-01 00:44:06.500        0 days 00:01:23  21.243921
3 1900-01-01 00:44:29.500        0 days 00:01:46  27.130791
4 1900-01-01 00:44:47.500        0 days 00:02:04  31.737906
```

Or using [`Series.pct_change`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.pct_change.html):

```
df["diff(%)"] = df["diff(s)"].pct_change() * 100
```